# How to save file name in listbox?

Tags: c#, wpf

My load button is in the WPF main window and my listbox is in the user control so now what I want to do is that the name of the file that I load with the load button should come inside the listbox in the user control.

The problem with this code is that when the user control is opened by clicking the UserControl object_placement button and then loading the file by clicking the Load button, the file name is not added to the listbox.

And if the object is loaded with the Direct Load button, the name is added to the listbox

Both the Load button and the Object_Placement button are in the WPF main window

```
private void Object_placement_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   settingpanel.Children.Clear();
   UserControl1 newFormControl = new UserControl1();
   settingpanel.Children.Add(newFormControl);
}
```

```
private void loadbtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
   dlg.DefaultExt = ".swl";
   dlg.Filter = "SWL files (*.swl)|*.swl";
   Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();
   if (result == true)
   {
      string swlFilePath = dlg.FileName;
      string swlFileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(swlFilePath);
      string swlZipFilePath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), swlFileName + ".zip");

      if (File.Exists(swlZipFilePath))
      {
         File.Delete(swlZipFilePath);
      }

      // Copy the selected file to the new .zip file
      File.Copy(dlg.FileName, swlZipFilePath);

      // Extract the .zip file to a temporary directory
      string extractDirectory = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Path.GetRandomFileName());
      ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(swlZipFilePath, extractDirectory);
      string Stlfilpath = Path.Combine(extractDirectory, swlFileName+".stl");


       // Add the object name to the existing list
       string stlFileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Stlfilpath);
       myUserControl.objectListBox.Items.Add(stlFileName);

     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must delegate the collection that contains the file name items from the main window to the `ListBox` inside the `UserControl` using data binding.

**MyUserControl.xaml.cs**

```cs
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
  public IList FileNameItemsSource
  {
    get => (IList)GetValue(FileNameItemsSourceProperty);
    set => SetValue(FileNameItemsSourceProperty, value);
  }

  public static readonly DependencyProperty FileNameItemsSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "FileNameItemsSource",
    typeof(IList),
    typeof(MyUserControl),
    new PropertyMetadata(default));

  public MyUserControl()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
  }
}
```

**MyUserControl.xaml**

```xml
<UserControl>
  <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=FileNameItemsSource}" />
</UserControl>
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window>
  <MyUserControl FileNameItemsSource="{Binding FileNames}" />
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public ObservableCollection<string> FileNames
  {
    get => (ObservableCollection<string>)GetValue(FileNamesProperty);
    set => SetValue(FileNamesProperty, value);
  }

  public static readonly DependencyProperty FileNamesProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "FileNames",
    typeof(ObservableCollection<string>),
    typeof(MyUserControl),
    new PropertyMetadata(default));

  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
  
    this.DataContext = this;
    this.FileNames = new ObservableCollection<string>();
  }

  private void loadbtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
    dlg.DefaultExt = ".swl";
    dlg.Filter = "SWL files (*.swl)|*.swl";
    Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();
    if (result == true)
    {
      ...  

      // Add the object name to the existing list
      string stlFileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Stlfilpath);
      this.FileNames.Add(stlFileName);
    }
  }
}
```